# How to identify which MP3 file ended in MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my ativity's onCreate(), I set a MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, then play an MP3 file:

```
    MediaPlayer p = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.intro);
    p.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    p.start();
```

And when playing ends, I just handle this event in:

```
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
      // handle completion
    }
```

All nice and dandy but now I want to play **two** different MP3 files and handle completion *differently* based on *which* file was played.

Is there a way to tell from the `MediaPlayer` parameter which piece ended?

Comment: Well the event setup has the parameter from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html as the MediaPlayer which according to your code is 'p'. Each OnCompletionListener identifies the appropriate 'p' (or media that has ended)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback `public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)` gives you a reference to the MediaPlayer.

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if (mp.equals(p){
        //do action for media player p

    } else if (mp.equals(q)){
        //do action for media player q
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not looking to identify which media player object/instance ran but rather which **mp3 file** finished playing.

Comment: p plays p.mp3 and q plays q.mp3. If player p (q) stops, you know now that p.mp3 (q.mp3) completed.

Comment: @Raz +1 for the clarification. No need for subclasses etc. but `q` and `p` must be "global" at the class level (i.e. data members, not automatic variables).

Comment: try calling them (global variables) or (method variables) instead of (data members) and (automatic variables).  There are a ton of interchangeable descriptors for the different scopes of variables, but (global) and (method) are pretty much universally understood.

Answer (score 2):

The OnSetCompletionListener triggered identifies which MediaPlayer completed. As to the mp3 file, your data model should be expressed as a list of MediaPlayer objects (objects may be create from subclass of MediaPlayer) which should know the mp3 file they are playing or completed playing. See http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/ for example
As to the model create a class that inherits from MediaPlayer. In that new class maintain the mp3 file name - like 'fn'. So then p.fn gives you the file for the mp3